# Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I got an array (see below for one object in the array) that I need to sort by firstname using JavaScript.
How can I do it?

```
var user = {
   bio: null,
   email:  "user@domain.example",
   firstname: "Anna",
   id: 318,
   lastAvatar: null,
   lastMessage: null,
   lastname: "Nickson",
   nickname: "anny"
};
```

Answer (score 1497, accepted):

Suppose you have an array `users`. You may use `users.sort` and pass a function that takes two arguments and compare them (comparator)

It should return

- something negative if first argument is less than second (should be placed before the second in resulting array)
- something positive if first argument is greater (should be placed after second one)
- 0 if those two elements are equal.

In our case if two elements are `a` and `b` we want to compare `a.firstname` and `b.firstname`

Example:

```
users.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.firstname < b.firstname) { return -1; }
    if(a.firstname > b.firstname) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
```

This code is going to work with any type.

Note that in "real life"™ you often want to ignore case, correctly sort diacritics, weird symbols like ß, etc. when you compare strings, so you may want to use `localeCompare`. See other answers for clarity.

Comment: Who would have thought strings could be sorted just by their value? Sweeeeet.

Comment: For those coming in at a later date, Mrchief's answer is better because it's case insensitive.

Comment: This code will only work on english speaking countries. In other countries you should be using [ovunccetin's answer with `localeCompare`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16481400/3713).

Comment: In ternary: `users.sort(function(a, b) { return (a > b ? 1 : (a === b ? 0 : -1)) })`

Comment: Dont forget to use the same text casing (e.g. 'toLowerCase()' ).

Comment: `users.sort(function(a, b) { return a.firstname < b.firstname ? -1 : a.firstname > b.firstname ? 1 : 0; })`

Comment: Are you applying sort to the object user, or array? array should be named users for better understanding

Comment: @commenters: Rewritten answers, added mention of "correct" sorting methods

Comment: What if a numerical field needs to be included along with the string field? @RiaD Suppose firstname + id. But id 10 should not be less than 5 as string

Comment: @Nisha, check firstname first, if they not equal return appropriately, if the equal, compare ids

Comment: it is buggy as won't work for string with different cases. You need to lowercase as well comparison strings

Comment: It is not working with the last record comes under array. It sort all the data perfect but doesn't sort last data. In my country list, Canada is coming at last (In array also, Canada is the last value). Please help to fix this.

Comment: your sort would be more efficient with an `else if` than with 2 tests `if > AND if < ` one excluding the other on each loop pass

Comment: wut? Code after return will not execute, so there's no difference.

Answer (score 1937):

Shortest possible code with ES6!

```
users.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname))
```

[String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) basic support is universal!

Comment: People should be aware this may be slower with large data sets. I'd recommend benchmarking if this is critical code

Comment: how to inverse order?

Comment: @chovy `users.sort((a, b) => -1 * a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname))` just multiply it by `-1`

Comment: If you want to use this to sort strings that may contain numbers, it does not work correctly. For example, `'7'.localeCompare('16')` returns `1`.

Comment: For strings with numbers to sort them out by the numbers (such as bank accounts, car plates, etc.): `users.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.replace(/\D/g, '').localeCompare(b.firstname.replace(/\D/g, '')));`

Comment: @chovy `users.sort((a, b)=> b.firstname.localeCompare(a.firstname))` just switch the order of things you pass to localeCompare

Comment: for case insensitivity  `(a, b) => a.firstname.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.firstname.toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 410):

Something like this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
 var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
 if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
  return -1;
 if (nameA > nameB)
  return 1;
 return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
});
```

Comment: When sorting strings 'toLowerCase()' is very important - capital letters could affect your sort.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering what the toLowerCase impacts, it's not much: `'a'>'A' //true` `'z'>'a' //true` `'A'>'z' //false`

Comment: @SimplGy I'd argue that its impact is a bit more than you're giving it credit for. For instance, as stated in the comments to the accepted answer, it's important to know whether or not your sort function will sort the string `'Zebra'` higher than the string `'apple'`, which it will do if you don't use the `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @PrinceTyke yeah that's a good case man. `'Z' < 'a' // true` and `'z' < 'a' // false`

Comment: All valid points and I'd say sorting is always a "it depends" kind of thing. If you're sorting by names, case sensitivity may not matter. In other cases it might. Regardless, I think adopting to one's specific situation is not hard once you get the core idea.

Comment: I like this answer because it is very clear. And for the people that don't know why (and how) this works ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort   which is actually a great website for JS. Thanks!

Comment: While using the `.toLowerCase()`, ensure your value is not null before calling it

Answer (score 410):

If compared strings contain unicode characters you can use [`localeCompare` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) of `String` class like the following:

```
users.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname);
})
```

Comment: String.localeCompare isn't supports Safari and IE < 11 :)

Comment: @CORSAIR it is supported, it is just the second and third parameter that aren't supported.

Comment: @CORSAIR the usage in the example is supported in all major IE browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare.  LocaleCompare also takes into account capitalization, so I think this implementation should be considered the best practice.

Comment: users.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname))    // Short n sweet ES6 version!

Comment: tanks bro. in ES6 use `users.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`

Comment: This, by far, is the most simplest answer!

Comment: Might want to wrap `a.firstname` in a `String` constructor to avoid null type errors/intellisense support too.

Comment: @RobertMolina String should be used with care as it may result in unwanted results, `String(null) === 'null'`.  Depending on the case there may be other unexpected values like numbers. `String(a.firstname ?? '').localCompare(b.firstname ?? '')` may be generally safer.

Answer (score 45):

Nice little ES6 one liner:

```
users.sort((a, b) => a.firstname !== b.firstname ? a.firstname < b.firstname ? -1 : 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This one is incomplete since it doesn't handle equal values properly.

Comment: Of course, thanks for spotting that, I have added a check for matching values

Comment: not bad I guess if you really want it all on one line, nested ternaries get confusing for readability though

Comment: @SamLogan this is really helpful, thank you for you contribution.

Answer (score 45):

We can use localeCompare but need to check the keys as well for falsey values

The code below will not work if one entry has missing lname.

```
obj.sort((a, b) => a.lname.localeCompare(b.lname))
```

So we need to check for falsey value like below

```js
let obj=[
{name:'john',lname:'doe',address:'Alaska'},
{name:'tom',lname:'hopes',address:'California'},
{name:'harry',address:'Texas'}
]
let field='lname';
console.log(obj.sort((a, b) => (a[field] || "").toString().localeCompare((b[field] || "").toString())));
```

OR

we can use lodash , its very simple.  It will detect the returned values i.e whether number or string and do sorting accordingly .

```
import sortBy from 'lodash/sortBy';
sortBy(obj,'name')
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy

Answer (score 20):

[underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) offers the very nice _.sortBy function:

```
_.sortBy([{a:1},{a:3},{a:2}], "a")
```

or you can use a custom sort function:

```
_.sortBy([{a:"b"},{a:"c"},{a:"a"}], function(i) {return i.a.toLowerCase()})
```

Comment: the second example involves returning strings. Does `sortBy` detect the returned values are strings and thus performs an alphabetical sorting? Thanks

Answer (score 19):

In case we are sorting names or something with special characters, like **ñ** or **áéíóú** (commons in Spanish) we could use the params **locales** (*es* for spanish in this case ) and **options** like this:

```js
let user = [{'firstname': 'Az'},{'firstname': 'Áb'},{'firstname':'ay'},{'firstname': 'Ña'},{'firstname': 'Nz'},{'firstname': 'ny'}];


user.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname, 'es', {sensitivity: 'base'}))


console.log(user)
```

The oficial locale options could be found here in [iana](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry), es (spanish), de (German), fr (French). About [sensitivity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters) **base** means:

> Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples: a ≠ b, a = á, a = A.

Answer (score 17):

A more compact notation:

```
user.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.firstname === b.firstname ? 0 : a.firstname < b.firstname ? -1 : 1;
})
```

Comment: it's more compact but violates its contract: `sign(f(a, b)) =-sign(f(b, a))` (for a = b)

Comment: return `a.firstname == b.firstname` should use `===` for completeness

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised no one mentioned Collators. You shouldn't use `localeCompare` unless you have to as it has significantly worse performance

```
const collator = new Intl.Collator('zh-CN'); // Chinese Simplified for example

function sortAsc(a: string, b: string) {
  return collator.compare(a, b)
}

function sortDesc(a: string, b: string) {
  return collator.compare(b, a);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Basically you can sort arrays with method sort, but if you want to sort objects then you have to pass function to sort method of array, so I will give you an example using your array

```
user = [
  {
    bio: "<null>",
    email: "user@domain.example",
    firstname: "Anna",
    id: 318,
    last_avatar: "<null>",
    last_message: "<null>",
    lastname: "Nickson",
    nickname: "anny",
  },
  {
    bio: "<null>",
    email: "user@domain.example",
    firstname: "Senad",
    id: 318,
    last_avatar: "<null>",
    last_message: "<null>",
    lastname: "Nickson",
    nickname: "anny",
  },
  {
    bio: "<null>",
    email: "user@domain.example",
    firstname: "Muhamed",
    id: 318,
    last_avatar: "<null>",
    last_message: "<null>",
    lastname: "Nickson",
    nickname: "anny",
  },
];

var ar = user.sort(function (a, b) {
  var nA = a.firstname.toLowerCase();
  var nB = b.firstname.toLowerCase();

  if (nA < nB) return -1;
  else if (nA > nB) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: why return 0 at the end?

Comment: =, when strings are same

Comment: but in that case shouldn't the `else` be removed? Otherwise that `return 0` will never be read

Comment: that is not "else", it's "else if"

Answer (score 9):

try

```
users.sort((a,b)=> (a.firstname>b.firstname)*2-1)
```

```js
var users = [
  { firstname: "Kate", id: 318, /*...*/ },
  { firstname: "Anna", id: 319, /*...*/ },
  { firstname: "Cristine", id: 317, /*...*/ },
]

console.log(users.sort((a,b)=> (a.firstname>b.firstname)*2-1) );
```

Comment: the sort function should return -1,0,1. this one only returns -1,1.

Comment: @RaduLuncasu - can you provide test data (users array) which shows that above solution gives wrong result? (as far I know, missing zero is no problem)

Comment: If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @RaduLuncasu ok, but that informations doesn't mean that zero is mandatory. The best way to show it is prepare data which not works - but as far I know this is impossible - e.g. `[9,8,7,6,5,1,2,3].sort((a,b) => a<b ? -1 : 1)`

Comment: Why are you using an array of numbers ? Why not try : [{firstname: "anna", id:1}, {firstname: "anna", id:2}] and see how the lack of 0 for equality will change the sorting of the array for no reason ?

Comment: @RaduLuncasu but OP needs on output sorted array - so botch cases `[{firstname: "anna", id:1}, {firstname: "anna", id:2}] ` and `[{firstname: "anna", id:2}, {firstname: "anna", id:1}]` are valid solutions (the only valid criterion given by OP is sorted by firstname).

Comment: I disagree, shouldn't change sorting for equal comparison, hence the JavaScript implementation of the compare function which uses 0 for that case.

Answer (score 8):

also for both asec and desc sort, u can use this :
suppose we have a variable *SortType* that specify ascending sort or descending sort you want:

```
 users.sort(function(a,b){
            return   sortType==="asc"? a.firstName.localeCompare( b.firstName): -( a.firstName.localeCompare(  b.firstName));
        })
```

Answer (score 7):

A generalized function can be written like below

```
    function getSortedData(data, prop, isAsc) {
        return data.sort((a, b) => (a[prop] < b[prop] ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1));
   }
```

you can pass the below parameters

1. The data which you want to sort
2. The property in the data by it should be sorted
3. The last parameter is of boolean type. It checks if you want to sort by ascending or by descending

Answer (score 6):

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18920254/872188) answer,

```
users.sort((a,b) => (a.firstname  - b.firstname));
```

Comment: Wrong wrong wrong! You don't get a valid result if you subtract strings in Javascript.

Comment: @xjcl did you run my code? This is working perfectly. https://jsfiddle.net/5uh34njg/

Comment: It's not working. The users are just output in the order of the input. Plus the field name you used there was `firstname` when it's actually `name` in your users object.

Comment: This gives NaN unless firstname is a number

Comment: I have no idea how this answer got so many upvotes. It's flat-out wrong. Even the provided supporting jsfiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, if you want to have a named sort-function, the syntax is as follows:

```
let sortFunction = (a, b) => {
 if(a.firstname < b.firstname) { return -1; }
 if(a.firstname > b.firstname) { return 1; }
 return 0;
})
users.sort(sortFunction)
```

Note that the following does NOT work:

```
users.sort(sortFunction(a,b))
```

Answer (score 4):

in simply words you can use this method

```
users.sort(function(a,b){return a.firstname < b.firstname ? -1 : 1});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for objects

```
transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
return array.sort((a, b) => a[field].toLowerCase() !== b[field].toLowerCase() ? a[field].toLowerCase() < b[field].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1 : 0);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pushed the top answers into a prototype to sort by key.

```
Array.prototype.alphaSortByKey= function (key) {
    this.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[key] < b[key])
            return -1;
        if (a[key] > b[key])
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built array method - `sort`. This method takes a callback method as a param

```
    // custom sort function to be passed as param/callback to the Array's sort method
    function myCustomSort(a, b) {
        return (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    // Actual method to be called by entity that needs sorting feature
    function sortStrings() {
        var op = Array.prototype.sort.call(arguments, myCustomSort);
    }

    // Testing the implementation
    var sortedArray = sortStrings("Burger", "Mayo1", "Pizza", "boxes", "Apples", "Mayo");
    console.log(sortedArray); //["Apples", "boxes", "Burger", "Mayo", "Mayo1", "Pizza"]
```

Key Points to be noted for understanding this code.

1. The custom method, in this case, `myCustomSort`, should return +1 or -1 for each element pair(from the input array) comparison.
2. Use `toLowerCase()`/`toUpperCase()` in the custom sorting callback method so that case difference does not affect the correctness of the sorting process.

I hope this is clear enough explanation. Feel free to comment if you think, more info is needed.

Cheers!

Comment: Not a proper answer because it only performs less than and greater than checks and not the equal check.

Comment: it also does not bring enything new to the table, compared to any of the answers that have been sitting there since ~2011.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation, works great in older ES versions:

```
sortObject = function(data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var result = {};

    keys.sort();

    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];

        result[key] = data[key];
    }

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

for a two factors sort (name and lastname):

```js
users.sort((a, b) => a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : a.lastname.toLowerCase() < b.lastname.toLowerCase() ? -1 : a.lastname.toLowerCase() > b.lastname.toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar, to get rid of **case sensitive**

```
users.sort(function(a, b){

  //compare two values
  if(a.firstname.toLowerCase() < b.firstname.toLowerCase()) return -1;
  if(a.firstname.toLowerCase() > b.firstname.toLowerCase()) return 1;
  return 0;

})
```

Comment: Same answer as the one by Mrchief. With the further disadvantage that the toLowerCase is done four times per comparison instead of two times.