# Javascript, string, RegEx, if and else if, console.log different output

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I want to output a string's vowels in order, so I decided to use RegEx to do it.

However, when I put the expression in different position in (if and else if), the output is different for the same expression. Could anyone explain?

```
function ordered_vowel_word(str) {

  if(str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) !== ""){
  var arr = str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g);
      console.log(arr);
  }
  else
      console.log(str);
  }

ordered_vowel_word("bcg");
ordered_vowel_word("eebbscao");
```

/* The Output */

ordered_vowel_word("bcg");

==> null

ordered_vowel_word("eebbscao");

==> ["ee", "ao"]

But if I restructure the expression,

```
function ordered_vowel_word(str) {

  if(str.match(/[^aeiou]/) !== "")
      console.log(str); 
  else if(str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) !== ""){
  var arr = str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g);
      console.log(arr); 
  }
}
```

The output will be

ordered_vowel_word("bcg");

==> bgv

ordered_vowel_word("eebbscao");

==> eebbscao

Comment: What actually surprises you? Both your inputs satisfy the first `if` condition

Answer (score 1):

The return value of str.match the way you are using it is an array containing the matches when it matches. Also, it is not an empty string when there are no matches... it is actually null.

Try changing what you are testing for in your if condition to this:

```
str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) !== null)
```

Comment: Next problem: it's not `null` in OP's case

Comment: I changed to null and it ran as I envision OP expected. That []==[] is pretty weird, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: put some code so that it was obvious for OP what you mean

Comment: Correct but 'bcg'.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) is indeed null.

Answer (score 1):

Take note that `string.match` returns an **array** if there is at least one match, and it returns **null** if there is no match.

What I think you want is :

`if(str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) == null){ // no matches`

or

`if(str.match(/[aeiou]{1,}/g) != null){ //has a match`

As for the sorting, you have to do process the array you get with `str.match`.

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript) for sorting arrays. Yes, you can use `>` and `<` operators for characters.