# Sort by alphabetical order in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

i would like to know how can i sort by alphabetical order my list of username here is my code but it's not working. I re)edit my code

script.js:

```
function displayuser() {
  $("#mySecond").empty();
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/"+x+"/users.json",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      cors: true ,
            contentType:'application/json',
            secure: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("claire.pagniez@cubber.com:CC..11cc"));
            },
            success: function (data){
                for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {

          var username = data.users;
                          data.users.sort(function (a, b) {
                         return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
                     });

                var userid = data.users[i].id;
        var all = data.users[i];
        console.log(all);

            $("#mySecond").append('<option value="'+ userid +'">'+ username +'</option>')

                }
            },
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: "not working" isn't a particularly useful diagnosis of the problem

Comment: script.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: userarray.sort is not a function the error is saying

Comment: that's not how Array.prototype.sort work. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript

Comment: we'd need to see the actual structure of the `data`, though it does seem you sort `data.users[i].name` which appears to be the name (again, if this is an array, show us the data)

Comment: I don't think that userarray is an array. You reassign the variable on each iteration with only one value.

Comment: Is `data.users[i].name` an array?  From just the name, it looks like it might be just a string, which isn't something you can sort by itself.

Comment: i think usearray in your code is a string not array ,

Comment: you maybe want to do something like `data.users.sort(function(a, b) {return a.name < b.name ? -1 : +(a.name > b.name);})` where both `a` and `b` will be user records (e.g. compare `a.name` to `b.name`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i sort by alphabetical order my list of username

Assuming this is the username array `data.users`, you can sort it by name

```
data.users.sort(function(a,b){ return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });
```

and then render them

```
 for (i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) 
 {
     var user = data.users[i];
     $("#mySecond").append('<option value="'+ user.id +'">'+ user .name +'</option>')
 }
```

Comment: @GuillaumeNouhaud can you share what your user object look like?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to sort a string, you actually want to sort `data.users`, so you don't need to loop. Using `sort` combined with [`String.prototype.localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) you can achieve what you want:

```
        success: function (data){
            var users = data.users;
            users.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
            });

           // users is now sorted
        }
```

Comment: #axelduch If i do that i have a list of "object" see my screenshot i added to my post –

Comment: To me this seems to be another question, your initial question was answered. I suggest you create another one with the problem that came after the error disappeared.