# jquery: How to sorti divs by data: getting bad results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort that by usernames:

```
<div id="listPerformers">
  <div class="performer" data-username="lula">lula</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="hotesse1">hotesse1 </div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="marina">marina</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="sabrina">sabrina</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="aaa">aaa</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="hotesse2" >hotesse2 </div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="julia">julia</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="misssexy">misssexy</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="guitarreblack">guitarreblack</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="blacklove">blacklove</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="ddd">ddd</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="eee">eee</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="anna">anna</div>
</div>
```

And I do use that jscript

```
$('.performer').sort(function(a,b){
   return a.dataset.username > b.dataset.username
}).appendTo('#listPerformers')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ore0zqxt/

Problem is: it is badly sorted:

julia

anna

comes in first positions !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort function is not correct. You need to return `positive`, `negative` or `zero` value from compare function in case of `greater than`, `less than` or `equal`.

```
$('.performer').sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.dataset.username < b.dataset.username) return -1;
    if(a.dataset.username > b.dataset.username) return 1;
    return 0;
}).appendTo('#listPerformers');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.performer')
  .sort(function(p, c) {
    return (p.dataset.username > c.dataset.username) - (p.dataset.username < c.dataset.username);
  }).appendTo('#performers-list');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="performers-list">
  <div class="performer" data-username="lula">lula</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="hotesse1">hotesse1</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="marina">marina</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="sabrina">sabrina</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="aaa">aaa</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="hotesse2">hotesse2</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="julia">julia</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="misssexy">misssexy</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="guitarreblack">guitarreblack</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="blacklove">blacklove</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="ddd">ddd</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="eee">eee</div>
  <div class="performer" data-username="anna">anna</div>
</div>
```