# jquery sort array of items (containing objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I sort the following by 'name' property ?

```
staticdata.items = [
  {id: '0', 'name': 'ABC'},
  {id: '0', 'name': 'XYZ'},
  {id: '0', 'name': 'DEF'}
]
```

So in the end, staticdata.items should look like

```
staticdata.items = [
  {id: '0', 'name': 'ABC'},
  {id: '0', 'name': 'DEF'},
  {id: '0', 'name': 'XYZ'}
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript

Comment: I'm sorry to be rude, but with your current reputation, you should have searched before posting question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way.

```js
var items = [{
  id: '0',
  'name': 'ABC'
}, {
  id: '0',
  'name': 'XYZ'
}, {
  id: '0',
  'name': 'DEF'
}]

var sortedItems = items.sort(function(pv, cv) {
  return pv.name > cv.name;
})

console.log(sortedItems);
```