# Sort a list in App Inventor 2

Tags: list, sorting, app-inventor

How can I sort a list in App Inventor 2 using WebViewString property? The list is too big to use javascript sort method and other ways work too slowly. Thanks in advance

Comment: create a html file and store it in the assets of your app, [see some examples here](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html) and pass the list in the webviewstring property. [How does the property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring) See also [this snippet](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring2)

Comment: Hello Taifun. I had already seen the examples and snippets you have posted but I don't know how to write the sort instruction (I'm a beginner). If you have, please show me an example. Thanks anyway

Comment: The 'sort instruction' is the same as shown [here](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2sort), you only have to use it in a html document... You might want to *try something* and in case you still have issues then *edit* your question and show us what you have... See also [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see also [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6712080/1545993)...