# Order Template7 Data Alphabetically

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-framework-7

I'm working with Framework7 and learning every day. All smooth but now I don't find the solution to this.

I use a template7Data code inside my-app.js with a lot of items that I render in a page later. For example:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    precompileTemplates: true,
    template7Pages: true,
    template7Data: {
        cars: [
            {
                internalID: 01,
                name: Renault,
            },
            {
                internalID: 02,
                name: Ford,
            },
            {
                internalID: 03,
                name: Tesla,
            },
        ],
    }
});
```

My problem is that when my page loads this "list" of items I want to be orderer alphabetically, instead of the order that I have written in the code above. In this example, the result that I have is:

```
Renault
Ford
Tesla
```

How can I do to obtain the order alphabetically of "names" ignoring the "internalID".

Hope I'm clear, my english is kinda poor :P

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do a sort function ([related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript#answer-6712080)). There are many others answers on stackoverflow ;)