# Typescript Array sorting

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

How do I sort an array of objects alphabetically in Typescript. I have array in this format now -
[image]
I am looking to sort it alphabetically by the channel field.

Here is what I tried which I got from the web.It didn't show any errors and also it didn't produce the expected result as well.

```
 this.currentPickSelection = this.currentPickSelection.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.channel > b.channel) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.channel < b.channel) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
```

Comment: your `json` object is wrong

Comment: Why each array has an array again inside? You've to change the JSON object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

Comment: @Saiyaff, I am trying to do that, But I am not sure how it happens.

Comment: @Tsvetan Ganev Thats the link I got that code snippet from. I was not able to solve with that posting, thats why I created another one.

Comment: @Sumchans I've edited the answer with the format of how the array of objects has to be. Hope that might help you with that. Because you're using an array without any reason as it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array. Your `array#sort` method should be

```
this.currentPickSelection.sort((a, b) => a[0].channel.localeCompare(b[0].channel))
```

Comment: That Worked. Thanks @Saiyaff Farouk

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to sort an array of objects.

Change your JSON object as an array of objects.

```
[
    {
        "pickCode":"",
        "cbsCode": "",
        "channel": "",
        "logo": "",
        "tag": ""
    },
    {
        "pickCode":"",
        "cbsCode": "",
        "channel": "",
        "logo": "",
        "tag": ""
    },
    {
        "pickCode":"",
        "cbsCode": "",
        "channel": "",
        "logo": "",
        "tag": ""
    }
]
```

Write a reusable function like this. (Same logic you've used. I've added the `toLowerCase()` part)

```
private compare(a, b) {
 if (a.channel.toLowerCase() < b.channel.toLowerCase()) {
  return -1;
 }
 if (a.channel.toLowerCase() > b.channel.toLowerCase()) {
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

And then, let's assume that arrayOfObjects variable name is `channelDetails`,

simply `this.channelDetails.sort(this.compare);` would do this.