# Sort array by year and month

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, lodash

I have the array as below,

```
let  yearAndMonth  =  [
    { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" }
]
```

I want to sort the array by **year** first and after that sort **month** from the year,

I want the output like this,

```
yearAndMonth  =  [
    { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY " },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" }
]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

Comment: This question solution not an quite easy, but still many people posting this as duplicate with others..stupid things. finally accepted solution very fine working with me....Thank you everyone for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `lodash` library for sorting data by multiple column.

I have created a demo on  **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sort-array-by-year-and-month?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**. I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

lodash  - **[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#orderBy)**

> Component.html

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Month</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let datas of sortedData">
    <td>{{datas.year}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.month}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Component.ts

```
 sortedData: any[];
  data = [
    { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY" },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "MARCH" },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "APRIL" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" }
  ];

monthArray: any = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE",
        "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sortedData = _.orderBy(data, [(datas) => datas.year, (user) => (this.monthArray.indexOf(user.month))], ["asc", "asc"]);
    console.log(this.sortedData);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for providing solution with lodash library.

Comment: Rather than importing an entire library to do a basic thing like sorting, try [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/): `data.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.year - b.year) || (monthArray.indexOf(a.month) - monthArray.indexOf(b.month));})`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I agree it's overkill, but if he is using the library already for other purposes, `_.orderBy()` is also simple.

Answer (score 5):

You could take an object for the month names and their numerical value.

The chain the order by taking the delta of year and month.

```js
var array =  [{ year: 2013, month: "FEBRUARY" }, { year: 2015, month: "MARCH" }, { year: 2013, month: "JANUARY" }, { year: 2015, month: "FEBRUARY" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var MONTH = { JANUARY: 0, FEBRUARY: 1, MARCH: 2, APRIL: 3, MAY: 4, JUNE: 5, JULY: 6, AUGUST: 7, SEPTEMBER: 8, OCTOBER: 9, NOVEMBER: 10, DECEMBER: 11 };
    return a.year - b.year || MONTH[a.month] - MONTH[b.month];
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array for months names and sort like this:

```js
let data = [
  { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" }, { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" },
  { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY" }, { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" }
];

let months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE",
              "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

data.sort(
 (a, b) => (a.year - b.year) || (months.indexOf(a.month) - months.indexOf(b.month))
);


console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a map which maps the Month to the month number and then use `Arrays.sort()` with your own custom comparator :

```js
let months = { 'JANUARY' : 1, 'FEBRUARY' : 2, 'MARCH' : 3, 'APRIL' : 4, 'MAY' : 5, 'JUNE' : 6, 'JULY' : 7, 'AUGUST' : 8, 'SEPTEMBER' : 9, 'OCTOBER' : 10, 'NOVEMBER' : 11, 'DECEMBER' : 12 };
let  yearAndMonth  =  [ { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" }, { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" }, { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY" }, { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" } ];

yearAndMonth.sort((a,b)=> a.year - b.year || months[a.month.toUpperCase()] - months[b.month.toUpperCase()]);

console.log(yearAndMonth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are ok with using `lodash` this can be achived by a simple `sortBy`

`_.sortBy(yearAndMonth, a => new Date(1+ a.month + a.year))`

It will construct a `new Date` for each month and year (with date 1) and that should work the way you want.

```js
let  yearAndMonth  =  [
    { "year": 2013, "month": "FEBRUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "MARCH" },
    { "year": 2013, "month": "JANUARY" },
    { "year": 2015, "month": "FEBRUARY" }
]

let res = _.sortBy(yearAndMonth, a => new Date(1 + a.month + a.year));
console.log('Sorted Result: ', res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note: You do not need to have *array/object/map* of all the months for this to have a look up to perform `>` or `<`

Comment: I got the "Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'" this error when i use your solution in angular.

Comment: @AniketAvhad either use **[1, a.month, a.year].join('')** or use simply with **+** operator without array, I have edited accordingly, you faced the problem of type checking at compile time.

Comment: Thanks, now your solution working fine.

Comment: I believe this should be promoted to the best answer as that will help the community, and the people visit to this question!

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the month names in an array to get the relative value of the month string when comparing with each other.

First comparison will be on the year, if both the year values are same then proceeding with the month comparison based on the months array created.

```
let months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE",
          "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];



yearAndMonth.sort((a,b) =>{
    if(a.year > b.year) return 1;
    else if(a.year <  b.year) return -1;
    else {
        if(months.indexOf(a.month.toUpperCase()) > 
           months.indexOf(b.month.toUpperCase()))
               return 1;
        else if(months.indexOf(a.month.toUpperCase()) < 
         months.indexOf(b.month.toUpperCase())) 
               return -1
        else return 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See also: [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/svy5zatw/)

Allow me to provide a plain ES version (sort array of objects on 1 or more key values, serial dependant (sort on 1, sort 2 within 1, sort on 3 within 1 and 2 etc.), non mutating, i.e. keep the original array as is):

```js
const log = (...str) => 
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += `${str.join("\n")}\n`;
const data = getData();
const xSort = XSort();
const months = [ "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE",
    "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER" ];

log( JSON.stringify(
    xSort
    .create(data)
    .orderBy( {key: "year"}, { key: v => months.indexOf(v.month) } ),
    null,
    " ")
  );

function XSort() {
  const multiSorter = sortKeys => {
    if (!sortKeys || sortKeys[0].constructor !== Object) {
      throw new TypeError("Provide at least one {key: [keyname]} to sort on");
    }
    return function (val0, val1) {
      for (let sortKey of sortKeys) {
        const v0 = sortKey.key instanceof Function ? sortKey.key(val0) : val0[sortKey.key];
        const v1 = sortKey.key instanceof Function ? sortKey.key(val1) : val1[sortKey.key];
        const isString = v0.constructor === String || v1.constructor === String;
        const compare = sortKey.descending ?
          isString ? v1.toLowerCase().localeCompare(v0.toLowerCase()) : v1 - v0 :
          isString ? v0.toLowerCase().localeCompare(v1.toLowerCase()) : v0 - v1;
        if (compare !== 0) {
          return compare;
        }
      }
    };
  }
  const Sorter = function (array) {
    this.array = array;
  };

  Sorter.prototype = {
    orderBy: function(...sortOns) {
      return this.array.slice().sort(multiSorter(sortOns));
    },
  };

  return {
    create: array => new Sorter(array)
  };
}

function getData() {
  return [{
      "year": 2013,
      "month": "FEBRUARY",
    },
    {
      "year": 2015,
      "month": "MARCH",
    },
    {
      "year": 2015,
      "month": "SEPTEMBER",
    },
    {
      "year": 2013,
      "month": "JANUARY",
    },
    {
      "year": 2013,
      "month": "MARCH",
    },
    {
      "year": 2013,
      "month": "APRIL",
    },
    {
      "year": 2015,
      "month": "FEBRUARY",
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```