# Sorting JSON Data in Alphabetical Order

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to read data from a JSON file and display it alphabetically. I am getting results but not alphabetically? I am not sure what has gone wrong here.

```js
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
  var user_Data = "";

  var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (name.a > name.b) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (name.a < name.b) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  $.each(sorted, function(key, value) {
    user_Data += '<p class="user col-md-6">' + value.name + '</p>';
  });
  $("#usernames").append("(" + data.length + ")"); //returns the total amount of contacts
  $("#usernames").append(user_Data);
});
```

Comment: Your `sort()` logic seems flawed; `a` and `b` are references to the objects to be sorted, yet you're using them as property accessors? It would be helpful to see a small example of `data.json`.

Comment: Also, don't reinvent the wheel.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Have a look at below links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the objects of the array while sorting

```
var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
```

so `name.a` and `name.b` should really be `a.name` and `b.name`