# Sort 2d array in Javascriptusing both fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a simple 2D array that I want to sort with two conditions.

```
[ [ "the,", 3 ], [ "who,", 3 ], [ "take,", 4 ], [ "over,", 4 ], [ "world,", 5 ] ]
```

1. Sort by number ascending
2. Then sort alphabetically descending

Expected result would be the `who` word. First step is achieved with below code:

`arraySorted = arrCom.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0]);`

Comment: Duplicate of [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45544166/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first comparison comes out to 0 (same number), use `localeCompare` to compare alphabetically:

```js
const arr = [ [ "the,", 3 ], [ "who,", 3 ], [ "take,", 4 ], [ "over,", 4 ], [ "world,", 5 ] ];
arr.sort(
  (a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || b[0].localeCompare(a[0])
);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you but still `the` appears first :)

Comment: Do you mean you want `z` `y` `x` etc? Just switch around the `a` and `b`

Comment: Yes, alphabetical descending.