# Edge and comparison / sorting

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have trouble figuring out how the Edge browser is comparing values in javascript.
I was sorting an array and my code works fine in Firefox but not in Edge. Here is an example from the MDN page:

```js
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(numbers);
```

When you paste this in the Edge console, the result is `(5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, as expected.

But if you use `>` instead of `-` (my goal is to compare strings), then...

```js
let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a > b);
console.log(numbers);
(5) [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
```

The sorting is not working. So I guess this is because `sort` is waiting for an integer and not a boolean. (Note that the code above is working fine in Firefox).

Now, my problem is that I want to compare strings. My code looks like this:

```js
results = elems.sort((a, b) => {
  return getPropertyOrEmptyString(a, propName) > getPropertyOrEmptyString(b, propName);
});
```

This code is sorting fine in Firefox but not in Edge, once again probably because `sort()` wants an integer not a boolean, but how can I compare string then? I mean, if I write `["b", "a"].sort()` in Edge it works, so it can compare them... I guess I should use an `Intl.Collator` but that seems complicated for a simple string comparison...

Comment: in short: sorts wants three values (<0, 0, >0), but not only two (0, >0).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript

Comment: So basically I need to add a ternaire to return an integer. But how is the `sort()` without parameters working for strings then...