# How to save a list with dicts in cookies in JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of data which contains some dicts.

```
data = []
data[0]['id']=5  data[0]['title']=''
data[1]['id']=6  data[1]['title']=''
data[2]['id']=4  data[2]['title']=''
data[3]['id']=0  data[3]['title']=''
data[4]['id']=9  data[4]['title']=''
data[5]['id']=1  data[5]['title']=''
```

Yep, I fixed everything. Thank you.
What about cookies?
How can I save my list in JS cookies?

Comment: sqlite? if so do sort with an `ORDER by id` clause in the query

Comment: besides, I think this question may be a dupe. [Sort array by * (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript), [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1):

Sorting can be done like this:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.sort` is your friend here. Your Array will be mutated this helper method so you may want to copy it first.

```js
let data = [], ids = [5,6,4,0,9,1]
for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  data.push({id: ids[i], title: ''})
}
const sorted = data.slice(0).sort((a,b)=>a.id - b.id)
```