# Sort properties alphabetically

Tags: webstorm

Given this JS code or CSS code in the WebStorm IDE:

```
const foo = {
  z: 'zip',
  a: 'zot'
}
```

or

```
.foo {
  z-index: 1;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Is there a way to select the code and reorder the property names alphabetically? To make:

```
const foo = {
  a: 'zot',
  z: 'zip' 
}
```

or

```
.foo {
  align-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You have a slight error in your CSS. Declarations are separated by semicolons `;`, not by commas `,`.

Answer (score 5):

For CSS, you can enable **Sort CSS properties** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | Style Sheets | CSS | Arrangement** and then use **Code > Rearrange Code**

For JS, no options are there out of the box. But you can use a third-party [String manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation) plugin that supports lines sorting

Comment: BTW: the IDE also has the `Edit | Sort Lines` action for a while now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218836. But yes, String Manipulation plugin is better and has many more other useful actions available (reverse order; case-insensitivity etc).

Comment: This sort all lines. I want to sort by property

Answer (score 0):

To sort properties in CSS, SCSS, Less, Sass, JavaScript, or TypeScript in WebStorm, follow these steps:

**- For Style Sheets (CSS, SCSS, Less, Sass):**

1. Open the settings with Ctrl + Alt + S.
2. Navigate to 'Editor | Code
   Style | Style Sheets | CSS'.
3. In the Arrangement tab, check 'Sort CSS
   properties'.
4. Make sure 'By name' is also checked. For both TS and
   JS, you can follow the same steps - I am going to use my case,
   TypeScript:

**- For TypeScript and JavaScript:**

1. Go to 'Editor | Code Style | TypeScript'.
2. In the Arrangement tab, look for the Matching rule (the second rule box).
3. Select the rule you want to sort by name with a double click.
4. An 'Order:' option will appear at the end; choose 'order by name'.

[image: Window showing the desired window]

[image: Rule edit]

I selected 'order by name' for all my rules and this is my final result:

[image: my matching rules 1]
[image: my matching rules 2]

You can customize these rules and create your own if needed. For example, you can set specific ordering for Angular component methods like ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy by adding custom rules.

[image: custom naming order]

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

CSS = Styling

JS = Animations / Logic, which is really CHANGING the behavior.

Therefore:
Use JS for that. [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript)

happy to help

Comment: I feel you've misunderstood the question. It is about sorting the lines in the source code using the IDE, not sorting things at runtime.

Comment: Ah you are right