# Reorder Collection with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm new to underscore so pardon my ignorance.

Is there a quick and easy way to do the following:

```
men:{gerald:{"name":"Gerald", "age":50},mike:{"name":"Mike", "age":50},charles:{"name":"Charles", "age":50}}
```

Where name is Mike - set at position 1 (index 0)

I just want to shuffle the items so the first item is set by the name I choose.

Any help more than welcome.

Comment: Do you need a random shuffle?  If no, just find the one you want and swap it with the first one?

Comment: Thanks - how do I do that? I'm new to named object collections - always worked in arrays = I'd do collection[0] = object

Comment: That's not valid json. You should _never_ see `{{` in JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected it now. I have no problem ordering an array. but am struggling with the data structure above.

Comment: @Chin: It doesn't make any sense to order an associative array...

Comment: Yes I know, I've just got to do something quick and dirty. Not my design.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You want to make the first item "mike". An associative array has no first element. You need to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need underscore.js. `Array.sort` will do fine:

```
myJson.men.sort(function(a, b) { return b.name == "Mike" })
```

This isn't really model usage of sort, but it does the job.

---

<s>Also, your JSON is invalid. You need square brackets around the array, not curlies:</s>

```
{
    "men": [{
        "name": "Gerald", "age": 50
    },{
        "name": "Mike", "age": 50
    },{
        "name": "Charles", "age": 50
    }]
}
```

---

#### Edit:

You can't "order" that JSON. What you're asking to do is order an associative array. This doesn't make any sense. If order of items is important, you want an array, not an object.

Comment: This is the point - its not an array but a object of objects.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, that's how it's coming and now I need to change the order. I can do all the converting etc, I know - but I was wondering whether there was a easy way to reset the order of the associative array.

Comment: @Chin: It doesn't have any order - there is no concept of order in an associative array!

Answer (score 1):

Since `_.suffle` shuffles all elements, you'd need to splice out all elements but the predefined one, shuffle them, and concatenate the shuffled elements to an existing array which contains the predefined element.

Something like:

```
var orig = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    shuffled = [];

shuffled[0] = orig[2]; // 3 is the predefined element

shuffled = shuffled.concat( _.shuffle( orig.slice(0,2).concat( orig.slice(3) ) ) );
```

which gets the array without the predefined element, shuffles it, and concatenates it to the `shuffled` array, which contains the predefined variable as its first element.