# Sorting values in an object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a JSON object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359761/sorting-a-json-object-in-javascript)

I have an object with key and value pair.

```
var obj = {
   'key1':'z',
   'key2':'u',
   'key3':'a',
   'key4':'c',
   'key5':'b',
   'key6':'e'
}
```

I have to sort my values in alphabetical order like this, but look at the keys they have also changed accordingly.

```
    var obj = {
           'key3':'a',
           'key5':'b',
           'key4':'c',
           'key6':'e',
           'key2':'u',
           'key1':'z'
   }
```

Comment: Not all browsers let you specify the order of keys of objects.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort object properties. Object properties behave like a hash map where the iteration order of properties may not reflect the order in your source code or JSON payload.

You should look into storing your data as an Array:

```
var arr = [{
   key: "key1", value: "z"
}, {
   key: "key2", value: "u"
}, {
   ...
}];

var sorted = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.key === b.key ? 0
        : a.key < b.key ? -1 : 1;
});
```