# How to sort an associate array by value's property

Tags: javascript

How would you sort an associative array by the values properties? The value itself is an object with multiple properties and one of the properties of the object is a string. I want to be able to rearrange the array alphabetically by the string. Is that possible?

I tried looking for answers in several places including here:
[How to sort an array of associative arrays by value of a given key in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php)

[How to sort an associative array by its values in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)

[How to sort an (associative) array by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788051/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-value)

I don't think those answered my question... not least not in a way I understand. Any help would be appreciated.
Example:

```
Object = {
    1: obj.prop = "C", 
    5: obj.prop = "A, 
    3: obj.prop = "B
}
```

I would want:

```
Object = {
    5: obj.prop = "A",
    3: obj.prop = "B",
    1: obj.prop = "C"
}
```

Comment: (1) JavaScript objects are *somewhat* like "associative arrays" but they really aren't quite the same, and (2) properties in objects have no particular order; "sorting" doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to extract an *array* of property names, sort that however you like, and then iterate through it to visit object properties in that order.

Comment: second link works perfectly

Comment: @John Object properties can start with a digit as long as they are strings. `{"0":1}` is a valid object and so is `{"0":1,"00":1}`.

Comment: What was it about the other questions and answers that you did not understand? If you have a separate question about those answers, then post that question; otherwise, this is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe I'm just not smart enough but the other answers didn't feel applicable or I just couldn't discern what information I needed to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, associative arrays (object) don't have an order.

This means it will be impossible to store the result in an object. Instead, you can store it in a array of {key,value} object.

```
var obj = {
    "1":{prop:"C"},
    "5":{prop:"A"},
    "3":{prop:"B"},
}

var res = [];
for(var i in obj){
    res.push({
        key:i,
        value:obj[i]
    });
}   

res.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.value.prop > b.value.prop ? -1 : 1;
});

/*res == [
    {key:5,value:{prop:"A"}},
    {key:3,value:{prop:"B"}},
    {key:1,value:{prop:"C"}},
]*/
```

Comment: I think in the sort, the ternary operator should be a.value.prop > b.value.prop ? 1 : -1; instead but you gave me what I needed to figure it out. Thank you so much!