# JavaScript: Sort an nested array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an nested array **unsorted** after sorting it should be **sorted** depending on 2nd item of sub-array

```
var unsorted = [["tag_17",0,4],["tag_18",13,18],["tag_435",6,11]];
var sorted = [["tag_18",13,18], ["tag_435",6,11], ["tag_17",0,4]];
```

Comment: btw, you have a nested array.

Comment: Sorry, Wrong choice of words :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var a = [
  ["tag_17", 0, 4],
  ["tag_18", 13, 18],
  ["tag_435", 6, 11]
];

a.sort(sortFunction);
console.log(a);

function sortFunction(a, b) {
  if (a[0] === b[0]) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (a[1] < b[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

You can read the documentation about [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked...

Comment: You're welcome. Up-vote and mark it as close. Happy Coding!!! :)

Comment: Found a working answer here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/12788202/2597670

Comment: Yes, just Google or StackOverflow and could have found multiple answers as `sort` is straight-forward and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var unsorted = [["tag_17",0,4],["tag_18",13,18],["tag_435",6,11]];

sorted = unsorted.sort((a,b) => {
    return b[1] - a[1];
} )

console.log(sorted);
```