# Is it possible to filter and arrange a list by keyword relevance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a list of items with multiple classes (keywords) like

```
<ul>
<li class="domestic tail feline">Cat</li>
<li class="wild tail canine">Wolf</li>
<li class="domestic tail canine">Dog</li>
<li class="wings beak domestic">Parrot</li>
<li class="wild tail feline">Lion</li>
</ul>
```

And then on the previous page a user selects 3 features from a select box and clicks next. Saving the keywords using localstorage, how can you, with javascript or jQuery, then display the list in order of most matching keywords?

So if I had input domestic, feline and wings the first item in the list would be Cat followed by Parrot, then Dog, Lion, and Wolf.

Comment: I'll point you to the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) methods to get you started.

Comment: I just recently found this plugin http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/ ... could this be relevant? I'm not really sure

Answer (score 1):

Not using jQuery, you would have to put those words and their keywords into an array.

Then loop through them comparing them to the 3 selected words to give them a value/score.

Then you would have to order these words based on the their scores. Here is a link about sorting a javascript array :
[How to sort an associative array by its values in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)

Using that ordered array you can loop through it to create the list-items and dynamically write them into a div using the "innerHTML" property.

I would setup an array like so(there are several ways you could go about this):

```
var listItems = new Array();
function listItem(displayWord){
    this.word = displayWord;
    this.keywords = new Array();
    this.matches = 0;
}

listItems['cat'] = new listItem('cat');
listItems['cat'].keywords.push('domestic');
listItems['cat'].keywords.push('tail');
listItems['cat'].keywords.push('feline');

for (x in listItems) {
    for (var c = 1; c < listItems[x].keywords.length; c++) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what is happening here? What is displayWord? and what is calling the listItem function?

Comment: This is just my preferred way of setting up the array of "display words" where "displayWord" is the word displayed in the list item. The listItem function is being used like an object/class. You could start a new list item like so : listItems['Wolf'] = new listItem('Wolf');

Answer (score 0):

```
var $ul = ..., // the list element
    keywords = ["domestic", "feline", "wings"]; // get that list from an input,
                                                // localstorage or whereever
$ul.children().sort(function(a, b) {
    var score = 0,
        $a = $(a),
        $b = $(b);
    for (var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++)
        score += $a.hasClass(keywords[i]) - $b.hasClass(keywords[i]);
        // if only a has the keyword, it adds 1, if only b has it 1 is substracted,
        // and if they both have if or not the score does not change.
    return score;
}).appendTo($ul); // re-append in the right order
```

This is a simple example of sorting a jQuery selection, you could make it more performant if you assigned each element a score of matching keywords and compared those numbers only.