# Sort an associative array by value and keep values?

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary, associative-array

I have an associative array:

```
     var map = new Array();
     map["exampleKey"] = 7;
```

The keys are strings and the values are integers. Some keys may have the same value.

I tried solutions from similar questions like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)
However, I have not found one yet that preserves the values. They simply create arrays with the keys in order. I need a sort that stores the keys and values in order (sorted by value) into some appropriate data structure.

I do not have a server so any solution must be JavaScript.

Comment: I think the solution you linked in your question describes rather well that pure associative arrays don't exist in JS; what it does have is only incidentally similar. What you want sounds like something you'll need to roll yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no associative arrays in JavaScript (setting aside the `Map` class in ES2015). Object properties cannot be ordered; the runtime delivers property names by all APIs in an arbitrary order.

What you can do is grab the property names into an array via `Object.keys()` or some equivalent, and then sort that array and access the object properties in order by iterating through that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can always post the array back to your own server (via ajax) and let PHP asort (or arsort) deal with it.

Alternatively read this:

[How to sort an associative array by its values in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I actually do not have a server and the website is entirely front-end and hosted on github-pages. I should have mentioned that.