# Trying to sort array by numbers first and then letters last

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array. I am trying to sort by "itemCommodity". I need to sort by numbers only first and then numbers with letters last. For example:

1000
A120
B330
2020
J954
5000

Should be displayed as:

1000
2020
5000
A120
B330
J954

I hope someone can help me out with this. I have an example of what i was trying below but it does not work as expected.

```
var product_data = [{
"itemCommodity": "1000",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "B330",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "A120",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "J954",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "5000",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "2020",
}]

 product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.itemCommodity - b.itemCommodity;
 });
```

Please note that itemCommodity is not the only object in the array. I have about 40 different objects, just trying to sort on itemCommodity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to compare them like this

```
product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.itemCommodity > b.itemCommodity;
});
```

And if you want the order of the letters to be sorted then you can try this

```
 product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.itemCommodity.toLowerCase() > b.itemCommodity.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: I thought this solution is fine and even better than mine, but I was wrong. It works only when the letter is on the first place in the string. If it's in the middle or at the end - it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly sort the elements which doesn't contain any letter. Then - sort the rest comparing their first character.

```js
var product_data = [{a:"1000"},{a:"B330"},{a:"A120"},{a:"J954"},{a:"5000"},{a:"2020"}],
    x = product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return /[A-Za-z]/.test(a.a) - /[A-Za-z]/.test(b.a) || a.a.charCodeAt(0) - b.a.charCodeAt(0)
    });

    console.log(x);
```

**In case** that you have simultaneously lowercase and uppercase letters, you will have to transform them all into one, mutual case and then sort them:

```js
var product_data = [{a:"1000"},{a:"B330"},{a:"a120"},{a:"J954"},{a:"5000"},{a:"2020"}],
    x = product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return /[A-Za-z]/.test(a.a) - /[A-Za-z]/.test(b.a) || (a.a.toUpperCase() < b.a.toUpperCase() ? -1 : a.a.toUpperCase() > b.a.toUpperCase() ? 1 : 0)
    });

    console.log(x);
```

Comment: This is amazing, how does this work? Doesn't `.test()` return a boolean?

Comment: at first i thought - _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."_ but on the more abstract case where letters arent at the front then this is the way to go. Have a +1

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks, really appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal as a note for future devs wondering the same thing (because it is weird looking), as `-` is an arithmetic operator, performing `true - false` js coerces the booleans into numbers (same way `null + ''` would give a string of null) so it translates `1 - 0`

Answer (score 3):

Since, as per ASCII table, numbers come first and then alphabets you can sort them using `sort()` method directly as follows;

```
["1000","A120","B330","2020", "J954", "5000"].sort()
```

results

```
["1000", "2020", "5000", "A120", "B330", "J954"]
```

However, as you don't have the array directly (given in your example), you can iterate all the nodes of JSON and compare them directly;

```
"1000" > "A120" => false; "1000" < "A120" => true
```

So there is just small correction in you code;

```js
    var product_data = [{
    "itemCommodity": "1000",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "B330",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "A120",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "J954",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "5000",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "2020",
    }]
    
     product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
         return a.itemCommodity > b.itemCommodity;
     });
    
    console.log(product_data);
```

Comment: its a json file

Comment: "1000" > "A120" => false; "1000" < "A120" => true

Comment: @AmitGupta this is not an answer to the question asked. In fact this is not an answer at all. User has an array of objects that he would like to sort by an attribute.

Comment: @Craicerjack I agree because I think initially the question was just about to sort the array not the json. Now since the question is modified Answer can also be modified.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It works only when the letter is on the first place in the string. If it's in the middle or at the end - it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Kinduser, I tried to change the letters. And it worked for me. Can you plz give me an example?

Comment: Try `["100a0","A120","B330","2020", "J954", "5000"]`. Even if there's a letter 'a' in the first element, it will be still on the first place.

Comment: It is working for me. `{
"itemCommodity": "100b0",
},
{
"itemCommodity": "100a0",
}`

returns `{ itemCommodity: '100a0' },
  { itemCommodity: '100b0' }`

Comment: But you have modified every element. Modify only one - the first one and see the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137627/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-kind-user).

Answer (score 3):

You can use localeCompare() method to sort the data.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
var product_data = [
  {
    itemCommodity: '1000',
  },
  {
    itemCommodity: 'B330',
  },
  {
    itemCommodity: 'A120',
  },
  {
    itemCommodity: 'J954',
  },
  {
    itemCommodity: '5000',
  },
  {
    itemCommodity: '2020',
  },
];

var sorted_data = product_data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.itemCommodity.localeCompare(b.itemCommodity, undefined, {
    numeric: true,
  });
});

console.log(sorted_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

For sorting an array in JS what you are describing is default behaviour.

```js
var myArray = ["123","A123","345","C123","B123"]
myArray.sort();
console.log(myArray);
```

Though for an associative array you may want to look at this post:

[How to sort an associative array by its values in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)

Comment: this is not the only object in the array, i have about 40 or more. itemCommodity is just one of them

Comment: Its not an associative array. Its an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is sort of what you were looking for. It's kinda verbose, but it gets the job done. Assuming you do not know what the keys of the objects are this will sort the objects based on their values without prior knowledge of key. Sorts numbers first in ascending order and then strings in ascending order. You can change this order by changing the `compare` functions returns and the `sort` functions returns for numbers.

```js
var numbersAlphAscending = (a, b) => {
  // get unknown keys
  var currentKeyA = Object.keys(a)[0];
  var currentKeyB = Object.keys(b)[0];
  
  // if item is a number
  if (Number(a[currentKeyA]) && Number(b.itemCommodity)) {
    return a[currentKeyA] - b[currentKeyB];
  }

  // if item is a string
  if (!Number(a[currentKeyA]) && !Number(b[currentKeyB])) {
    return a[currentKeyA].toLowerCase() > b[currentKeyB].toLowerCase();
  }

  // numbers before strings
  return Number(a[currentKeyA]) ? -1 : 1;

}

var product_data = [{"itemCommodity": "1000",},{"itemCommodity": "B330",},{"itemCommodity": "A120",},{"itemCommodity": "J954",},{"itemCommodity": "5000",},{"itemCommodity": "2020",}]

console.log(product_data.sort(numbersAlphAscending));
```

Comment: thats not sorting in order though. they need to be in numerical and alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map` to create an array and sort it using `sort`.

```js
      var numArray = [];
    var product_data = [{
    "itemCommodity": "1000",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "B330",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "A120",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "J954",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "5000",
    },
    {
    "itemCommodity": "2020",
    }]


     product_data.map(function(value, index) {
       numArray.push(value["itemCommodity"]); 
    })

        numArray.sort();
        var newNum=(numArray.join(","));
        alert(newNum);
```

Comment: He doesnt have an array of strings, he has an array of objects.

Comment: @Craicerjack I have sorted out the problem .Hope you find it correct now

Comment: The OP wants `product_data` to be sorted so you'll have to recreate an array of objects with the newly sorted order for this to be a complete solution @Anonymous

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It works only when the letter is on the first place in the string. If it's in the middle or at the end - it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. `reduce` the array into two arrays- one without letters, another
   with letters
2. Sort the order of each array
3. Finally, concat the two sorted array together

```js
var product_data = [
 { "itemCommodity": "1000" },
 { "itemCommodity": "B330" },
 { "itemCommodity": "A120" },
 { "itemCommodity": "J954" },
 { "itemCommodity": "5000" },
 { "itemCommodity": "2020" }
];

product_data
  // We reduce into two array - one without letters, another with letters
  .reduce((arr, record) => {
    const index = (record.itemCommodity.match(/[a-z]/i)) ? 1 : 0;
    arr[index].push(record);
    return arr;
  }, [[],[]])
  // We sort the two array respectively
  .map((arr) => arr.sort((a,b) => a.itemCommodity > b.itemCommodity))
  // We concat the two sorted array
  .reduce((curr, next) => curr.concat(next));

console.log(product_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this small trick of string based comparison only when both values are non-numeric, else use numeric sorting.

```
var product_data = [{
    "itemCommodity": "1000",
   },
   {
   "itemCommodity": "B330",
   },
   {
   "itemCommodity": "A120",
   },
   {
   "itemCommodity": "J954",
   },
   {
   "itemCommodity": "5000",
   },
   {
   "itemCommodity": "2020",
   }
];

product_data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b))
        return a.itemCommodity.toLowerCase() > b.itemCommodity.toLowerCase();
    else
       return +a.itemCommodity.toLowerCase() > +b.itemCommodity.toLowerCase();
});
```