# Reorder an object by the value, but preserve key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object:

```
 teamTotalChances = {
  AFC Wimbledon: 71.43,
  Accrington Stanley: 28.57,
  Barnsley: 64.28999999999999,
  Birmingham City: 114.28,
  Blackburn Rovers: 71.43
 }
```

That I want to order by the value (highest to lowest) so that it would then be:

```
teamTotalChances = {
 Birmingham City: 114.28,
 AFC Wimbledon: 71.43,
 Blackburn Rovers: 71.43,
 Barnsley: 64.28999999999999,
 Accrington Stanley: 28.57
}
```

I have tried a few things including `Object.keys` and `Array.from` but I can't get it to display key and value. At the minute I've got it ordered with the correct key but the value is lost:

```
keysSorted = Object.keys(teamTotalChances).sort(function(a,b){return 
teamTotalChances[b]-teamTotalChances[a]});
```

`keySorted` is then an Array which looks like this:

```
keySorted = [
 0: "Birmingham City",
 1: "AFC Wimbledon",
 2: "Blackburn Rovers",
 3: "Barnsley",
 4: "Accrington Stanley"
]
```

So the order is right, but I've lost the numeric value!

Thank you.

Comment: Objects do not have order. Object.enteries and sort that or sort the keys by the value and just use that key array to reference the value in the object.

Comment: Why? What is your use case?

Comment: I think you want to have an array of objects and sort that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an associative array by its values in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199901/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-by-its-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert them to a manageable source. What I did is first convert each one to a key/value object array, then sorted that array from highest to lowest.

```js
let teamTotalChances = {
  'AFC Wimbledon': 71.43,
  'Accrington Stanley': 28.57,
  'Barnsley': 64.28999999999999,
  'Birmingham City': 114.28,
  'Blackburn Rovers': 71.43
}

let result = Object.keys(teamTotalChances).map(itm => { return { key: itm, value: teamTotalChances[itm] } })

console.log(result.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value))
```

Comment: Yes perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does this output representation suit you?:

```
[
  ["Birmingham City", 114.28],
  ["AFC Wimbledon", 71.43],
  ["Blackburn Rovers", 71.43],
  ["Barnsley", 64.28999999999999],
  ["Accrington Stanley", 28.57]
]
```

If yes, that could be the code:

```
 let teamTotalChances = {
  "AFC Wimbledon": 71.43,
  "Accrington Stanley": 28.57,
  Barnsley: 64.28999999999999,
  "Birmingham City": 114.28,
  "Blackburn Rovers": 71.43
 }

console.log(Object.entries(teamTotalChances).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]))
```

Comment: Yes, yes it does! Just a note for others this sorted it with lowest value first so I just swapped b[1] and a[1] around. I then looped through this array as so:    teamEntries.forEach(function(team) {
        console.log(team[0]+ " "+team[1]);
    });